# SeekBar с двумя ползунками Android Studio

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как подобное можно реализовать, чтобы на одном seekbar было два ползунка(точки?)? Может готовые библиотеки есть? Кто юзал?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел пару библиотек [android-range-seek-bar](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar), [Windowed Seek Bar](https://bitbucket.org/nimbusgb/windowed-seek-bar), [тут подробно обсуждают этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795773/android-seekbar-with-two-thumbs)